# Does there exist a non-negative unbounded function on a compact metric space such that $\sup_{\mu \in U} \int Ld\mu < \infty$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $U$ be the class of probability measures on a compact metric space $S$ (hence tight). Is it possible to find a function $L:S \to \Bbb R^+$ such that $L$ is unbounded and $$\sup_{\mu \in U} \int Ld\mu < \infty$$

Comment: Of course, we could change a measurable function over a set of measure zero to "make it unbounded", but this is probably not the kind of thing you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no.  For any unbounded $L:S \to \Bbb R^+$, it suffices to consider a sequence $(x_n)\subset S$ for which $L(x_n) \to \infty$.  Then, we may define a sequence of measures by 
$$
\mu_n(A) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & x_n \in A\\
0 & x_n \notin A
\end{cases}
$$
It is then clear that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int L\,d\mu_n = \infty$.

Comment: The class of probability measures $U$ is already given, how can you construct new measures $\mu_n$?   You can take a look at this. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2527440/on-why-a-set-of-probability-measures-is-tight-iff-there-exists-a-non-decreasing

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ measurable, positive and unbounded. Then there are infinitely many integers $n\ge 1$ for which  the subsets
$\{ x \ | \ n \le f(x) < n+1\}$ are non-void, let these be $m_1< m_2 < m_3 < \ldots $. Clearly $m_k \ge k$ for all $k$. Consider a probability measure $\mu$ on $S$ such that for all $k\ge 1$  the non-void subset $\{ x \ | \ m_k \le f(x) <m_k +1\}$ has size $\frac{1}{k(k+1)}$. Then
$$\int_S f d \mu \ge \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{m_k}{k(k+1)} \ge \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{k}{k(k+1)}= \infty$$